# Android: error with CircularProgressButton

Tags: android, xml, binary-xml

The `CircularProgressButton` give me error, and I don't know how to fix it.

This is the code:

`xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Seleziona città:"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/spin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            >
        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- This line is 63--><com.dd.CircularProgressButton
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/cpbLogin"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:cpb_cornerRadius="48dp"
                        app:cpb_textIdle="INVIO"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`Java` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private Button button;
public String s;
CircularProgressButton circularProgressButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    setS(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    circularProgressButton = (CircularProgressButton) findViewById(R.id.cpbLogin);

    circularProgressButton.setIndeterminateProgressMode(true);

    circularProgressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(circularProgressButton.getProgress()==0)
            {
                circularProgressButton.setProgress(30);
            }
            else if (circularProgressButton.getProgress()==-1)
            {
                circularProgressButton.setProgress(0);
            }
            else if (circularProgressButton.getProgress()==100)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, tab.class);
                intent.putExtra("message", getS());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void setS(String ss){
    s=ss;
}

public String getS(){
    return s;
}

int i = 0;
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String sSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    if(i==0){

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, sSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    i++;
    setS(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Drawable d;

    switch (s){
        case "Carpi": d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.carpi); img.setImageDrawable(d); break;
        case "Berlino": d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.berlino); img.setImageDrawable(d); break;
        case "Trieste": d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trieste); img.setImageDrawable(d); break;
        case "Lubiana": d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lubiana); img.setImageDrawable(d); break;
        case "Norimberga": d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.norimberga); img.setImageDrawable(d); break;
        default: break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

This is the error that `android-studio` give me:

```
Process: esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info, PID: 25577
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info/esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class com.dd.CircularProgressButton
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2568)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5690)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class com.dd.CircularProgressButton
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6161)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5690) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6161) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5690) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758) 
               Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimension(TypedArray.java:566)
                  at com.dd.CircularProgressButton.initAttributes(CircularProgressButton.java:196)
                  at com.dd.CircularProgressButton.init(CircularProgressButton.java:84)
                  at com.dd.CircularProgressButton.<init>(CircularProgressButton.java:73)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6161) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5690) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963) 
                  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
```

This is the `gradle`:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
```

I tried some solutions but none of those solve my problem

Comment: Post  xml layout. `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3`

Comment: what should I change?

Comment: there must be a spelling mistake or the view is not in `com.dd` anymore please recheck library package name and where the `CircularProgressButton` really is!

Comment: Well, it's `app:cpb_cornerRadius="48dp"` that's causing that, but I can't see anything wrong there. Maybe I'm missing something. Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding?

Comment: now I try______

Comment: I change `com.dd.CircularProgressButton` in `CircularProgressButton` and I did the cleaning and the rebuilding, but android-studio give me the same error: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class CircularProgressButton`, and I removed `cornerRadius`

Comment: Ok I tried with `com.dd.CircularProgressButton` and I removed `cornerRadius` and now it worked but the button is not clickable, how to fix this?

Comment: How exactly are you determining that it's not clickable? Have you put a log print, or a breakpoint in `onClick()`?

Comment: I solved now, thank you very much Mike M.

Comment: The problem was the CornerRadius

Answer (score 0):

check name : com.dd.CircularProgressButton ,maybe you wrong pakage name